# Reading URL from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had everything working flawlessly until I decided to implement apache, mod rewrite. There's 2 values, 2 parameters which information I need. I was using:

```
        $scope.scan_id = $location.search().scan_id;
        $scope.scan_domain = $location.search().scan_domain;
```

And, of course, it was working without any problem.
**As The previous URL was:**

```
http://domainname.com/scanner/view_scan.html#?scan_id=10&scan_domain=clarin.com
```

So now, **The current URL structure is:**

```
http://domainname.com/scanner/view/scan/id/10/domain/clarin.com
```

I'm looking for a simple approach using $location service. I thought about something like a regex to look for **scan/id/([0-9]){0,9999}/** and **domain/(.)*** but I certainly have no idea how to approach this in AngularJS.

Thanks in advance!

**addendum:**

In case it's not clear, I'm trying to get the values of the scan id and the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$location.path()` to get the path of the URL 
i.e

if the URL is `http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo`

you would get $location.path() --> `/some/path`

As you said there would be no params. First get the path and then split the URL accordingly.

For example, see the below:

```js
var myUrl = 'http://domainname.com/scanner/view/scan/id/10/domain/clarin.com',
    path = '/scanner/view/scan/id/10/domain/clarin.com',
    scanID,
    domainName,
    firstSplitStr,
    secondSplitStr; 
//path is what the $location.path() service would return you. 

firstSplitStr = '/scanner/view/scan/id/'; //as you already know the format

secondSplitStr = '/domain/'

scanID = path.replace(firstSplitStr, '').split(secondSplitStr)[0];

domainName = path.replace(firstSplitStr, '').split(secondSplitStr)[1];

console.log(scanID, domainName);
```

Comment: Yeap, nice approach... I was using also VanillaJS as I couldn't find any specific way in angular, without falling into routes, which I prefer to avoid at this point. In the other hand $location.path() isn't reading the path itself, so I'm getting the data from $location.absUrl()

Comment: Probably the fact that I decided not to the # method isn't making the things easier...

Comment: I don't know why the $location.path() is not working for you. But $location.absUrl() will also serve your purpose. 

See this example for more details of using $location without hashbang mode.

http://www.angularjshub.com/code/examples/routing/01_LocationService/html5/mypath?param1=value1&param2=value2#hashval

Comment: Thanks bro, I own you a drink @OverTheMoon ;)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make use of plain, vainilla JS, and regexes.

```
$scope.analizar_posicion = function() {

        //revisamos si los params no poseen información
        if (!$scope.scan_id || !$scope.scan_domain ) {

            //procesamos la dirección
            var address_now = $location.absUrl();

            //buscamos el scan id
            var scan_id_expresion = /scan\/id\/([0-9]{0,9})/i;
            var scan_id = address_now.match(scan_id_expresion);
            var scan_id = scan_id[1];
            console.log(scan_id);

            //buscamos el nombre de dominio
            var scan_domain_expresion = /domain\/((.){1,99})/i;
            var scan_domain = address_now.match(scan_domain_expresion);
            var scan_domain = scan_domain[1];
            console.log(scan_domain);

            //asociamos las variables al scope.
            $scope.scan_id = scan_id;
            $scope.scan_domain = scan_domain;

        }

    }
```